# WSDL and DISCO file from webservice

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, web-services, wsdl

Not so long ago, I've tried creating a webservice for sharepoint.
I followed this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx). In this tutorial you can see that you also need to
create a wsdl and disco file. I didn't do this, and everything still worked.
So my question is:

Why would you need that files? (some more infromation or links)

Thanks!

Comment: Hm.. if this is a general question about WSDL and disco, this may be off topic for SharePoint.SE and should probably be posted on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the .disco file from the tutorial. That is only if you want auto-discovery. You do however need the WSDL file, if you intend to be able to involve the web service reference using a dynamic url address.

Unlike most web services that are deployed from a static and well-known endpoint location, SharePoint web services can be invoked from multiple access mappings from multiple virtual paths (/marketing/_vti_bin/search.asmx, /hr/_vti_bin/search.asmx). The custom .WSDL file is meant to provide a dynamic endpoint based on the virtual path you access the web service from.

On SharePoint 2010 you can also easily create a SOAP-based WCF service without having to gernate the disco or wsdl files. Here is my blog post on the subject:

http://blog.sharepointbits.com/2010/04/custom-wcf-services-in-sharepoint-2010_17.html